# MSVC 2012 generates different vtable pointer offsets for different files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, vtable, disassembly

Let's say I've got in X64 release configuration
It's a an obfuscated code snippet...

```
// Hdr1.h
// Dozen of includes

class Cls1
{
public:
    Cls1();
    virtual void bar();
// ...
protected:
// about 7 fields where some of them are of complex template type.
bool isFlag1 : 1;
bool isFlag2 : 1;
};


// Hdr2
// Dozens of includes
class Cls2
{
public:
    // ...
    void foo();
};
```

I've got separate translation units to implement these classes. Say from foo I try to access virtual method of Cls1::bar and I get a crash(access violation).

```
void Cls2::foo()
{
   //...
   Cls1 * pCls1 = // somehow I get this goddamn pointer

   pCls1->bar(); // Here I crash
}
```

From disassembly I see that Cls1::Cls1 puts vtable ptr at offset 8 to the very beginning of this. From disassembly of Cls2::foo I see that it takes pointer to vtable from offset zero. Debugger is also unable to see this vtable correctly. If I manually get vtable at offset 8 - addresses appear to be correct in this table.

The question is - why could this happen, what pragma could lead to this or anything else? Compilation flags are the same for both translation units.

Below I add a bit of disassembly:
This is a normal case that I face across the code:

```
 Module1!CSomeOkClass::CreateObjInstance:
 sub     rsp,28h
 mov     edx,4                                  ; own inlined operator new
 lea     ecx,[rdx+34h]                          ; own inlined operator new
 call    OwnMemoryRoutines!OwnMalloc (someAddr) ; own inlined operator new
 xor     edx,edx
 test    rax,rax
 je      Module1!CSomeOkClass::CreateObjInstance+0x40 (someAddr)
 **lea     rcx,[Module1!CSomeOkClass::`vftable' (someAddr)] ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass < vtable ptr**
 mov     qword ptr [rax+8],rdx                  ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass
 mov     qword ptr [rax+10h],rdx                    ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass
 mov     qword ptr [rax+18h],rdx                    ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass
 mov     byte ptr [rax+20h],dl                  ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass
 mov     qword ptr [rax+28h],rdx                    ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass
 **mov     qword ptr [rax],rcx                  ; Inlined CSomeOkClass::CSomeOkClass < offset zero**
```

Now let's see what I've got for Cls1::Cls1:

```
 Module1!Cls1::Cls1:
 mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
 push    rdi
 sub     rsp,20h
 **lea     rax,[Module1!Cls1::`vftable' (someAddress)]  ; vtable address**
 mov     rbx,rdx
 mov     rdi,rcx
 **mov     qword ptr [rcx+8],rax                ; Places at offset 8**
```

I assure you that Cls2 expects pointer to vtable to be at offset zero.

Compilation options are:
/nologo /WX /W3 /MD /c /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zm192 /bigobj /d2Zi+ /Zi /Oi /GS- /GF /Oy- /fp:fast /Gm- /Ox /Gy /Ob2 /GR- /Os

I noticed that Cls1::Cls1 heavily uses SSE instructions inlined from intrinsics.

**Compiler version:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x64**

Please pay attention that this code works ok on different platforms/compilers.

I managed to figure out that the problem was in fact with this bitfield I have in the very end of Cl1 definition. The ctor generated places pointer to vtable at offset zero if I make isFlag1 + isFlag2 ordinary bools. These flags are initialized in the ctor's initializer list. By commenting out class's code one by line I narrowed down the problem to this bitfield. In order to investigate this I used WinDbg, /P compiler option, compiled cpp unit manually with the original flags provided + /FAs /Fa. It appears that it is a compiler's bug.

Comment: Is that all of your code? Do you implement `Cls1::bar` anywhere or override it in a derived class that `pCls1` is supposed to point to?

Comment: So... how *did* you get that goddamn pointer?

Comment: @txtechhelp Yes I do override it in a different class that derives from Cls1 and the pointer actually points to it. But it is not important since both base class and its descendant place pointer to vtable at offset zero.

Comment: @iwolf I construct it with a custom new operator call, say new ClsDescendant(...), then I put it into collection, the pointer gets fetched out of a collection at some point and gets passed to Cls2. The pointer is correct since I checked the pointer right after operator new along with ClsDescendant::ClsDescendant returned. Upon return the code expects the pointer to vtable to be at offset zero, but as I mentioned previously both base class and descendant place the pointer at offset 8.

Comment: @txtechhelp I'm sorry. Base class and its' descendant place vtable pointer at offset 8 instead of zero.

Comment: @iwolf Please see my updated question.

Comment: @txtechhelp Please see my updated question.

Comment: As @iwolf stated, you need to post a minimal amount of code that actually reproduces the problem. With the exact code you have posted, there's no way of telling why you're getting a crash outside of invalid pointer references. The `vtable` has nothing to do with your crash beyond the fact that you, again, have an invalid pointer reference; an error of `access violation` usually means you're trying to access a pointer that points to a region of memory you don't have access to (i.e. an invalid pointer reference)

Comment: @Zorgiev: How many things does `ClsDescendant` inherit from? If you're actually getting a pointer-sized offset for a vtable pointer, it sounds like you've convinced at least part of your code that there are multiple vtables in play.

Comment: I managed to figure out - please see my updated question. There is a small portion of details added. First of all the problem was that this compiler flags combination in conjunction with vtable+bitfield I've got in the end of the class definition. When I made these flags as ordinary bools - this made compiler generating ctor correctly. Now I would like to know if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @iwolf Please see my comment above.

Comment: @txtechhelp Please see my comment above.

Comment: Guys, I'm not this stupid to ask obvious stuff like you thought I did. The problem is exactly like I described. I just cannot put this code here. It works in other build configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out that the problem was in fact with this bitfield I have in the very end of Cl1 definition. The ctor generated places pointer to vtable at offset zero if I make isFlag1 + isFlag2 ordinary bools. These flags are initialized in the ctor's initializer list. By commenting out class's code one by line I narrowed down the problem to this bitfield. In order to investigate this I used WinDbg, /P compiler option, compiled cpp unit manually with the original flags provided + /FAs /Fa. It appears that it is a compiler's bug.